# В чем основные различия между 2 и 3 уровневыми архитектурами?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, архитектура

Такая проблема. В планах проект оболочки экспертных систем, и стоит вопрос: Какую архитектуру использовать, двухуровневую или трехуровневую. Так как нет особого опыта стал смотреть различия, понял то, что различаются именно в доступе к данным. То что в двухуровневой архитектуре есть клиент, и есть сервер, и все, клиент как то на прямую взаимодействует с БД.

В трехуровневой же есть клиент, отправляет запрос на сервер, сервер обрабатывает его, отправляет запрос в бд, берет данные, модифицирует и отправляет ответ. Я правильно понимаю? Объясните пожалуйста если я не правильно понял, в чем различие.

И еще на практике: я писал WebAPI, где есть модели данных, есть класс DbContext(), есть сервисы моделей, в которых реализуются методы, которые как раз такие отправляют запрос к бд, получают данные, модифицируют и отправляют ответ. Контроллеры, которые используют эти сервисы и все. Это трехуровневая или двухуровневая архитектура?

Comment: основное различие между двух уровневыми и трех уровневыми архитектурами в наличии одного дополнительного уровня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас есть клиент с сервером и ваш сервер хранит данные напрямую (без участия базы данных) - это [двухуровневая (клиент-серверная) архитектура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%E2%80%94_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80).

Когда вы начинаете хранить данные в какой-либо отдельной базе данных, и делать запросы к ней из сервера, архитектура превращается в [трёхуровневую](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Что на счёт вашего случая "на практике" - по описанию это трёхуровневая архитектура.

Comment: спасибо большое!!!